# How to fix this ERROR in node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(50,73)

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, npm-start, npm-publish

I am getting an error in node_modules, how can I fix this `ERROR in node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(50,73)`

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(50,73): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(50,88): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(50,107): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(51,23): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(51,45): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(51,67): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(51,70): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(51,71): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(51,75): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(52,28): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(52,50): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(52,60): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(53,16): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(54,23): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(54,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(56,25): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(56,34): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(67,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

Comment: Have you given it the `;` it expects? :)

Comment: @karthi Verify that you're referencing a version of the moment-timezone typings that is compatible with your version of TypeScript. I recently ran into this and downgrading the version of @types/moment-timezone corrected the build errors.

Comment: @Karthi:are u fixed above issue?\

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

update the @types/moment-timezone@0.5.7  which will take care of this issue

Answer (score 1):

Change your code inside the package.json file.

Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` from your directory.

Then change the version and run `npm install`.

```
"@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.7",
```

to:

```
"moment-timezone": "0.5.23",
```