# ERROR in /node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (47,77): ';' expected. how to fix

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone, angular2-moment

I'm working in an Angular 4 application and everything worked fine until I clone my repo and runned npm install and ng serve

This error seems to be the problem

```
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (47,77): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (47,92): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (47,111): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,27): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,49): ')' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,71): Expression expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,74): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,75): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,79): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,32): ',' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,54): Expression expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,64): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (50,20): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (51,27): Expression expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (51,37): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (53,29): Expression expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (53,38): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (64,1): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (47,92): 'MomentZoneOffset' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (47,113): Cannot find name 'never'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,9): Cannot find name 'zonesForCountry'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,25): Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,42): Cannot find name 'country'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,51): Cannot find name 'string'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,51): Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,59): Cannot find name 'with_offset'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,73): Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,77): Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,95): Cannot find name 'string'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (48,106): Cannot find name 'never'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,9): Cannot find name 'zonesForCountry'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,25): Cannot find name 'country'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,34): Cannot find name 'string'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,42): Cannot find name 'with_offset'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,56): Cannot find name 'boolean'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,66): 'MomentZoneOffset' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (49,87): Cannot find name 'string'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (50,9): Cannot find name 'countries'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (50,22): Cannot find name 'string'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (51,9): Cannot find name 'guess'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (51,15): Cannot find name 'ignoreCache'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (51,29): Cannot find name 'boolean'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (51,39): Cannot find name 'string'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (53,9): Cannot find name 'setDefault'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (53,20): Cannot find name 'timezone'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (53,31): Cannot find name 'string'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (53,40): 'Moment' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts (63,15): Cannot find name 'MomentTimezone'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/src/app/pipes/timePipes/moment-timezone.pipe.ts (10,37): Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/src/app/pipes/timePipes/moment-timezone-2.pipe.ts (13,34): Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/src/app/pipes/timePipes/moment-timezone.pipe.ts (10,37): Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
ERROR in C:/Users/mypcuser/Desktop/myproject/src/app/pipes/timePipes/moment-timezone-2.pipe.ts (13,34): Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
```

So I researched and I found this ---> [How to fix this ERROR in node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(50,73)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247263/how-to-fix-this-error-in-node-modules-types-moment-timezone-moment-timezone-d-t)

but to me, it didn't worked, I updated many things, clean cache, reinstalling moment and moment-timezone and the problem is still there.

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.6",
    "@mdi/font": "^3.5.95",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "9.3.1",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.54",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.7",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.2.2",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.7",
    "angular-calendar": "0.21.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "5.0.0",
    "angular-xregexp": "^1.0.0",
    "angular2-datetimepicker": "^1.1.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^0.7.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "d3": "4.11.0",
    "docx": "^4.4.0",
    "double-slider": "^2.0.0",
    "dragula": "3.7.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "json-server": "^0.15.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "lrm-graphhopper": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^4.3.4",
    "ng-tiny-scrollbar": "^0.10.1",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.5",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ng4-datetimepicker": "^1.0.6",
    "ngx-bootstrap-product-tour": "^1.0.6",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-export-as": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^4.9.6",
    "ngx-quill": "1.3.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "particles.js": "^2.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.57",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^0.8.1",
    "polyline-encoded": "0.0.8",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "primeng": "^6.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "screenfull": "3.3.1",
    "simple-scrollbar": "^0.4.0",
    "simplebar": "^2.5.1",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "videogular2": "^5.6.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.4.6",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.3",
    "wd": "^1.11.2",
    "wd-bridge": "0.0.2"
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code inside the **package.json** file.

Delete **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** from your directory.

than change the version and run **NPM Install**

```
  "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.7",
```

TO

```
"moment-timezone": "0.5.23",
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would either check npm if environments were different or if global package messing your local.

Else, try installing a different version for moment-timezone.