# Moment-TimeZone node_modules error "moment-timezone/index.d.ts(47,77): error TS1005: ';' expected."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs

I have previously used moment in my project, and want to add the moment-timezone:

```
npm i moment-timezone
```

I import them at my project:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
import 'moment-timezone';
```

When I run it, I get errors:

```
"moment-timezone/index.d.ts(47,77): error TS1005: ';' expected."
```

I have downgraded to:

```
"@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.7",
```

according with: [How to fix this ERROR in node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts(50,73)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247263/how-to-fix-this-error-in-node-modules-types-moment-timezone-moment-timezone-d-t)

If I do above, I instead get following error in Reddux:

```
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(38,38): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

I also have tried lower versions of moment-timezone but still does not work. Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: `When I run it, I get errors` which version gets the first error?

Comment: what does that line look like in YOUR version of `moment-timezone/index.d.ts` ... the file looks fine in the repo

Comment: Line is "T extends true ? MomentZoneOffset[] : never;" (however, I got multiple syntax errors in node modules, this one is an example. 

First version is the current one:   "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
and : "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.7",

Comment: don't you mean `zonesForCountry<T extends true>(country: string, with_offset: T): T extends true ? MomentZoneOffset[] : never;` - perhaps you have an old version of typescript?

Comment: I have an older version of typescript but I cant change it since I develop for SharePoint (which does not support the latest versions).

Comment: "older version" ... how much older

Comment: Typescript version 2.4.2

Comment: I guess Typescript has changed a lot from that to 4.0 - I mean, you can't even use typescript playground with a version less than 3.3.3